# Copy / Paste a changing source specific columns into Sheet 2. Compare data in Sheet 1 & 2, if Column B data is new add new row to Sheet 1

Tags: excel, vba

I am relatively new to using VBA for Excel and want to create a sort of consolidated tracker for all ongoing projects. As such, I have the following use case (s):
The trigger should happen when I click on a Button.

**1. Copy / Paste data specific columns based on Header Name from a changing source file -**
a. Certain tools produce extract daily so the source name is always changing. I want the VBA code to pick up certain columns based on the header name of the column and paste them into Sheet 2 of my file (let's call it Test File).
b. I will create multiple Sheets for different tool extracts for reference purposes

**2. Compare Sheets 1 and 2 of the Test File _ Update as needed**
Once data is pasted from the source file into Sheet 2, I want the VBA to compare the data in Sheets 1 and 2
a. If Sheet 2 Column A = Sheet 1 Column A, then just compare the remaining columns to see if any data has been updated. If there are updates, I want them to be highlighted in light blue so I to review the changes
b. If Sheet 2 Column A is not found in Sheet 1 Column A, then I want the code to automatically add a row in Sheet 1 with relevant columns (A:D, F: G) copied from Sheet 2. I want these rows to also be highlighted in light blue for me to review changes.

Please let me know if this is possible to do, and what type of code would be needed for it. I have looked at a few other questions on this place + youtube to find some reference code, but it's hard to get it all to work together.

I looked at a few youtube videos and some other questions, but was not able to put together one code that would let me do this. Please find below some references I saved:

[image]

[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far? You note that 'it is hard to get it all to work together' so that sounds like you have some existing code ... please include it (as text) in your question. Additionally, replace the image with the actual links (again, as text).

Answer (score 0):

I think "spreadsheet compare" can help you.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).